# endpoints for python (app engine) won't produce discovery document

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

Suddenly after upgrading gcloud, I'm getting this error:

```
endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc -f rest
service_backend.main.PersonService Traceback (most recent call last): 
File
"/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py",
line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())   File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py",
line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)   File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py",
line 69, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import api_server   File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py",
line 86, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import cli_parser   File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/cli_parser.py",
line 40, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import runtime_factories   File
"/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/runtime_factories.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import custom_runtime   File
"/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/custom_runtime.py",
line 26, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import http_runtime   File
"/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/http_runtime.py",
line 53, in <module>
    import portpicker ImportError: No module named portpicker
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it please?

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to reproduce this error. So I filed a bug here with possible workarounds: [issue 63260172](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63260172).

To get around the issue while it's being triaged, you should install `portpicker` globally:

```
sudo pip install portpicker
```

or homebrew specific fix:

```
pip install --user --install-option=“--prefix=” portpicker
```